# How to structure / access useState array from parent server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm a beginner learning NextJS and React by building a simple e-commerce page that lists a table of products, and allows users to search and filter.

My understanding so far:

- Based on similar questions on StackOverflow, the parent component should generally fetch the data and pass it down to child components.
- From the React docs on "lifting up state", the parent component should handle the states and pass it down to the child

What I'm struggling with:

- I'm not sure how to follow React docs recommendation since my parent component is a server component, which means I can't `useState` since it's a client component.
- I can't figure out how to pass the `selectedFilters` state array from child to the parent. I need to do this in order to feed the active filters into the `fetchProducts` function (in the parent) so only products that match the checked filters can be displayed.

Am I thinking about this wrong or structuring things wrong?

##### Parent component -- Page.tsx

```
// Note: Missing array of filter state, only has searchQuery

export default async function Page({
    searchParams,
}: {
    searchParams?: {
        query?: string;
    };
}) {
    const query = searchParams?.query || '';
    const products = await fetchProducts(query);

    return (
        <div>
            <SideNav/>
            < ProductsTable products = { products } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

##### Child component -- sidenav.tsx

```
'use client';

const filters = [
    {
        id: 'brand',
        name: 'Brand',
        options: [
            { value: 'nike', label: 'Nike', checked: false },
            { value: 'adidas', label: 'Adidas', checked: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'type',
        name: 'Type',
        options: [
            { value: 'basketball', label: 'Basketball', checked: false },
            { value: 'running', label: 'Running', checked: false },
            { value: 'training', label: 'Training', checked: false },            
        ],
    },
]

export default function SideNav() {
    const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState(filters);  
    const updateFilters = (filterId: string, optionValue: string, checked: boolean) => {

        setSelectedFilters((prevFilters) => {
            return prevFilters.map((filter) => {
                if (filter.id === filterId) {
                    filter.options = filter.options.map((option) => ({
                        ...option,
                        checked: option.value === optionValue ? checked : option.checked,
                    }));
                }
                return filter;
            });
        });
    };



    return (

            {/* Search bar */}
            <div>
                <Search />
            </div>

            {/* Filters */}
            <div>
                    <form>
                        {selectedFilters.map((selectedFilters) => (
                            <div key={selectedFilters.id}>

                                <h3>{selectedFilters.name}</h3>

                                {selectedFilters.options.map((option) => (
                                    <div key={option.value}>
                                        <input
                                            id={`${selectedFilters.id}-${option.value}`}
                                            value={option.value}
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            checked={option.checked}
                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                updateFilters(selectedFilters.id, option.value, e.target.checked)
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <label
                                            htmlFor={`${selectedFilters.id}-${option.value}`}
                                        >
                                            {option.label}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                ))}

                            </div>

                        ))}
                    </form>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/77973830/15288641.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Thanks for sharing. In my case, I'm using `useState` to store array of active filters that the user clicks on, which is the challenge. I'm able to have the page work fine if all I have is a query string.

Comment: What about sending the array as multiple query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with NextJs, but the problem I think is that you have like two interactions, one is the first initial data coming from the server Page component that fetches products and propagates to the ProducsTable, and the other one is the filters interaction that is client side. The filter state can't be lifted unless you change the Page component to become a "client" one and manage the state there to fetch the products on the client side.

Another option would be making the filtering on the client side directly with the initial results, but it would depend on other things such as the necessity of dynamic pagination, number of els. to filter etc...

---

A common pattern to use in search pages that are server-side rendered is to manage state via URL, this lets you have only one source of truth for both server and client among other benefits like being able to share the URL.

You should update the URL with the client inputs, so whenever a user checks or unchecks any of your filters, you will update the URL adding and removing it as a query parameter. This will cause a new render flow from server to client, and you will be able to get the filter parameters from your Page component.

Be aware to have synced the client state for the different cases (selected filters, unselected filters etc..)

You can follow the tutorial of NextJs 14 where they use this pattern https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).